# Virus Infection Model (need help on solving ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently trying to model a simple epidemic model. 
I've set $I(t)$ as population infected by virus, $D(t)$ as population deceased by virus. 
Without considering newly born or naturally deceased, I've set the initial population as $N$, and the initial infectious population $I(0)= 1$.
With this precondition, I've came up with two equations.

(1) $I'(t)=kI(t)[N-I(t)-D(t)]$

(2) $D'(t)=dI(t)$

($k$:infectious rate, $d$:death rate)

I tried to solve two equations, and reached a conclusion:
$$I'(t)=NkI(t)-k{(I(t))}^2-dkI(t)Int I(t)dt$$

Sadly, because of my limits, I can't proceed further. Can someone help me out??

++D(0)=0

Comment: In a general sense, do not try to solve an ODE until you have taken a course in the subject.

Comment: You should add also $D(0)=0$. This is one among many models (see for example https://institutefordiseasemodeling.github.io/Documentation/general/model-si.html). What do your instructor want ? An explicit solution ? It is very unlikely that it exists...

Comment: It's an individual project, so it may be possible that solution does not exist. If it's impossible to derive explicit solution, is there any way to find properties of these function(eg. the max. population) Thanks. :)